# weird DOMDocument issue

Tags: php, domdocument

I have the following code:

```
$DOMDocument = @DOMImplementation::createDocument(null, 'html'); 
$width = array(200, 700);

$colgroup = $DOMDocument->createElement('colgroup');
foreach($width as $key => $width) {

   $precentageWidth = round(($width*100)/array_sum($width));

   $col = $DOMDocument->createElement('col');
   $col->setAttribute('width', 'test');

   $colgroup->appendChild($col);

}

$baseelement = $DOMDocument->documentElement;

$baseelement->appendChild($colgroup);


echo $DOMDocument->saveHTML();
```

Expected result:

```
<html><colgroup><col width="test"></col><col width="test"></col></colgroup></html>
```

Got result:

```
<html><colgroup><col width="test"><col width="test"></colgroup></html>
```

So my question is: the `</col>` tag is missing; why?

Comment: Notice; this can be fixed by using a str_replace.. NOTE: You won't see the </col> tag in your Chrome browser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.4.2), the `</col>` end tag is **forbidden**.

This is similar to the [`<img>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.2) - you would never write `<img src="x.png"></img>`, would you?

Because the end tag is forbidden, the DOM implementation correct omits it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Do you have/know some kind of work around of this?

Comment: Since the tag is forbidden, there is no workaround. But I suppose you could create an XML document instead.

Comment: Shouldn't it generate `<col width="test" />` then?

Comment: @DanFromGermany If this were XHTML, then sure. But it isn't. It's HTML. `/>` isn't really "a thing" in HTML. Proof: `<div />` doesn't behave the same as `<div></div>`. And even if it were and did, `<col />` would effectively be `<col></col>`, which is forbidden.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's not 100% correct. the `/>` doesn't imply an end-tag, it just says we have a void-tag which cannot have content. `<div />` is therefore invalid. `A void element is an element whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances.` [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html)

Comment: @DanFromGermany Hrm. Pretty sure I read somewhere that `/>` is shorthand for `></tagname>`. And that it's an XHTML thing, not an HTML thing. Point is, `<col>` is defined as a tag that is forbidden from having an end tag, so `<col>` is most correct. Although personally I write `<col />` anyway - it's just nicer to look at in my editor.